# Unable to connect to ethernet. ethtool reports unknown speed and unknown duplex

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, dhcp

I am trying to receive an internet connection through ethernet. My desktop is running Ubuntu 16.04.

The network manager applet reports as having connected to `enp0s31f6`, yet my computer has not received a DHCP address.

`dhclient` output seems to indicate that no `DHCPOFFER`s are being received from the server (more `DHCPDISCOVER` requests are sent with no change in the output):

```
~$ sudo dhclient -v enp0s31f6
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.3
Copyright 2004-2015 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/enp0s31f6/0c:9d:92:bd:9b:57
Sending on   LPF/enp0s31f6/0c:9d:92:bd:9b:57
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xfff5a066)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xfff5a066)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xfff5a066)
DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s31f6 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13 (xid=0xfff5a066)
```

`ethtool` reports the following information. The value of `Unknown!` for the `Speed` and `Duplex` attributes seems suspect. Will I ever be able to connect when these values are unknown? If not, how can I fix this unknown values problem?

```
~$ sudo ethtool enp0s31f6
Settings for enp0s31f6:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 2
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

I've tried to set their values manually, to no avail:

```
~$ sudo ethtool -s enp0s31f6 speed 1000 duplex full
~$ sudo ethtool enp0s31f6
Settings for enp0s31f6:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 2
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

Here's some snippets filtered from `dmesg`, in case they're relevant:

```
~$ dmesg | grep enp
[    1.719930] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
[    7.980215] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[    8.221865] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready
[  314.654059] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s31f6: link is not ready


~$ dmesg | grep e1000e
[    1.339047] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.339047] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.406037] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    1.651130] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    1.719235] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 0c:9d:92:bd:9b:57
[    1.719236] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    1.719304] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 12, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    1.719930] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: renamed from eth0
```

The Ubuntu Network Manager GUI reports that the 'Wired' connection is 'Connected', but there's no assigned address.

I've rebooted the machine at various points through the debugging so far, which did not fix the problem.

Additional info:

```
~$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:9d:92:bd:9b:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlxe091f519b0f3: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:91:f5:19:b0:f3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

~$ ip route 
default via ABC.DEF.176.1 dev wlxe091f519b0f3  proto static  metric 600 
default dev enp0s31f6  scope link  metric 1002 linkdown 
ABC.DEF.176.0/20 dev wlxe091f519b0f3  proto kernel  scope link  src ABC.DEF.188.112  metric 600 
HIJ.KLM.0.0/16 dev enp0s31f6  proto kernel  scope link  src HIJ.KLM.9.24 linkdown
```

[some IP numbers masked with letters in the above]

A potentially interesting bit from:

`journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`:

```
<info>  [1564430899.7494] device (enp0s31f6): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Jul 29 16:08:19 computer NetworkManager[947]: nm_device_get_device_type: assertion 'NM_IS_DEVICE (self)' failed
```

Comment: Look at `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`, and `ip route` and `ip link show`.

Comment: @waltinator thanks, I've added output from those commands. let me know if you think there's anything specific I should be looking for (particularly from the `journalctl` command, which outputs lots of info). I'll start looking around based on the info I just posted.

Comment: Check the cable you're using for your connection, and replace it if possible.  Because that can cause connection problems too.

Comment: `ip route` shows you haveTWO `default` routes. No wonder your system is confused!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the output of `ip link show` you see

> ```
> enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER
> ```

and `dmesg` shows

> ```
> enp0s31f6: link is not ready
> ```

both indicate that there exists a problem with the physical connection.

Some possible causes:

- a plug is not snapping into place properly
- a defective cable
- a switch port is deactivated or defective

Comment: In fact, my ethernet interface, which is intentionally not connected to a cable, also reports Speed: Unknown!

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't connect to the internet even when the cable was plugged in correctly (checked it with the other device) and got the  info. The reason was that both **Speed** and **Duplex** were not set and I needed to use **ethtool** to set the speed to 100 Mb/s and duplex to full:

`sudo ethtool -s <adapter_name> speed 100 duplex full`

where `<adapter_name>` is the name that shows for the adapter when using `ip a` command.

Also the same problem occurred on another OS (Windows 11) and it was due to the same reason - I needed to set speed and duplex in network settings.